# Callout from Batch Apex

Tags: batch, callout, future

I have a Apex Batch class which first does DML on the relevant records, and then makes a callout.  When I try running it, I get the error:

> You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

So I tried to workround this by making the method which does the callout (which  is in a separate class) future and able to make callouts:

```
@future(callout=true)
```

But now I get this error:

> Future method cannot be called from a future or batch

I can think of a couple of ways around this, neither of which is perfect.  I can either make the callout first, or create a second batch job to do the callout, and "chain" that second batch job after the first.  Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make the callout first and then do the DML? A callout can't be rolled back automatically, so it's important to make it before attempting any DML.

Comment: there's a wonderful example in Dan Appleman's Advanced Apex 3rd edition that has a scalable to millions of records processed in a batch where callouts are required - basically, the callout requests are written to a custom object and when that object is inserted, a queueable job starts. Read the chapter (7)

Comment: Did you actually implement `Database.AllowsCallouts`?

Comment: How is this Batch class invoked? Is it invoked  from a trigger